# How to Implementing search functionality in Expandable listview?

Tags: android, hashmap, expandablelistview

I am trying to implement search functionality in expandable listview using Hashmap. For showing expandable list view, I am passing hashmap through the adapter with the key as a String(Category) and value as a listview(Category Items). I don't know what code should be written for getting one exact item from the hashmap. I have tried one method but every time it returns the Category only not Items.

```
    HashMap<String, List<Expand>> hashmap_search = new HashMap<>();
          for (Map.Entry<String, List<Expand>> entry : hashmap.entrySet()) {

          for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().size(); i++) {

          if (entry.getValue().get(i).item_name.toString().toLowerCase().contains(search.getText().toString())) {
          Log.e("RAV", "getValue  " + (entry.getValue()));
          hashmap_search.put("Most Popular", entry.getValue());
          hashmap_search.put("Veg soups", entry.getValue());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
          adp_adi = new PersonAdapternew(FragmentHomee.this, totalclients, hashmap_search, mCartt, esssid_adi, mRestaruntName);
                            mrestlist.setAdapter(adp_adi);
```